# Loop inside @Schedule with new transactions

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, scheduled-tasks

I'm using an EJB with @scheduled annotation to loop over all my context entities every 10 secs. All Contexts entities are unrelated to each other and therefore should create new transactions for their update method:

```
@Stateless
public class UpdateService {

    @EJB
    ContextDao contextDao;

    @Schedule(second = "*/10", minute = "*", hour = "*")
    public void update() {
        for(ContextEntity context : contextDao.findAllContexts()) {
            updateContext(context);
        }
    }

    public void updateContext(ContextEntity context) {
         // load data from db
         // update some stuff
         // save back to db
    }
}
```

Now I wanna have an single transactions for the updateContext method. So if I get any error in one ContextEntity, only this transaction should be rolled back and not the whole loop.

1. What are the correct TransactionAttributes for update and updateContext?
2. Do I have to use a different EJB for the updateContext method?

Thanks

Comment: This is a good and helpful description, but I would not have found it. I would have looked for *nested* or *embedded* calling *same* EJB or something. Perhaps it could be renamed

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you want to call `updateContext` not `update` inside the loop.

The `update`-method as defined has the attribute `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED` which is default and can be left like way.

The `updateContext`-method should be annotated `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW`, but... if you want to call in that transaction-context, you must use

```
@Resource
SessionContext sessionContext;
```

and fetch the businessinterface from sessionContext to call `updateContext`

As example look at [SingletonEjb](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit/blob/master/ejb-cdi-unit-test-war/src/main/java/com/oneandone/ejbcdiunit/ejbs/SingletonEJB.java) see Method `methodCallUsingSessionContext`